# Google SpreadSheet Script to Set Current Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet script that moves a row from one sheet (*Review*) to another (*Reviewed*) when the checkbox in a cell (*column 20*) on the row is true. Please see a copy of the script below.

I need assistance in modifying the script so it sets a timestamp {`setValue(new Date())`} on the adjacent cell (*21*) when the cell (*column 20*) is set to true or as soon as it is moved to the target sheet (*Reviewed*). Thanks in advance.

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Review" && r.getColumn() == 20 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reviewed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

If you want to set the timestamp in the active sheet `s` then:

`s.getRange(row,21).setValue(new Date());`

or if you want in the target sheet `targetSheet` then:

`targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),21).setValue(new Date());`

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = event.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.range;
  if(s.getName() == "Review" && r.getColumn() == 20 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reviewed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    s.getRange(row,21).setValue(new Date());  
  //targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),21).setValue(new Date()); 
  }
}
```